# UI disappearing and Parse queries blocked at semaphore_wait_trap

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, semaphore

At a time in my app, the user have a timeline where are displayed posts from their friends, but randomly, the queries are stopped and not executed anymore,

more exactly, I had a problem before that: my app was frozen at `psynch_mutexwait`, I fixed it by using: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ });` for queries that runs on background thread, but more precisely:

**I have 2 queries that runs in loop every 3 and 4 seconds respectively, *made by 2 respective `shcheduled NSTimer`***

the first query loop for new posts (in this case the user do not have to refresh manually):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];

    [query whereKey:@"user" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query whereKey:@"user" containedIn:self.allFriends];

    [qFriendInfo findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

           //Used to display results in UICollectionView
            self.AllPosts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
});
```

the second query is querying users's state, for example if a user is "online", "offline", or "disconnected"

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:self.allFriendsIds];

    [qFriendInfo findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

        //Used to display results in UICollectionView
           self.allUsers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];   
        }
});
```

All works properly by using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ });`

but randomly, the queries are stopped (the app is not frozen either...) (I can see this by `NSLog` in the console) **and when I pause, in the left window I can see the background thread on `semaphore_wait_trap`**

does anyone have an idea for how to fix that issue ?